# Angularjs late control load

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

Is it possible to load the angularjs controller late? like...

```
function doLateLoad(){ app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {}) }
doLateLoad();
```

I get ctrl is not found error for some reason. If I directly load it w/o including into a function, it works well.

Comment: The code you provided is not 'late'. It's absolutely same as `app.controller(...)`. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that replicates the problem.

Comment: there are modules that make attempts to enable "Lazy Loading" which seems like what you are trying to ask here.... check out [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) for example.